# Speech Synthesis: How to change en-US accent to en-IN accent with google-speech

Tags: javascript, html, windows, google-speech-api, speech-synthesis

I've been trying to find an answer to this for weeks and I really need help so please answer. I'm working on a simple chatbot, everything works perfect but I want to change the en-US Male accent to en-IN Male using Speech Synthesis. I've tried literally everything and this is just not working. I have successfully console. logged the voices I have available in my computer and well it looks like I don't have en-IN but I do have en-GB and 20 other voices. I tried using recognition.lang = 'en-IN'; but that didn't work, I've also tried using double quotes on en-IN and tried using en_IN. I also tried a billion other things but this just won't change Its accent. I need this done by tomorrow and I really will appreciate anyone who tries to help me. Also, my script tag is internal, not external located in the body.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.talk');
const content = document.querySelector('.content');
const greetings = [
    'If you are good im good too.', 
    'Im doin alright', 
    'doing well.'
];
const weather = [
    'Ask the weatherman!', 
    'I recommend checking your phone or the news ' 
    
];
const name = [
 'My name is techwaala', 
 'its techwaala, because I love to code!'
];
const hello = [
 'Why hello! How are you doing today?', 
 'Hey there How are you?'
];
const hru = [
 'Happy to hear that!', 
 'Im so sorry to hear that', 
 'Feel better soon!'
];
const color = [
 'oooh that\'s a hard one, I have a lot of favorites.',
 'I have so many!'
];
const SpeechRecognition = 
 window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.lang = 'en-IN';
recognition.onstart = function() {
 console.log('voice is activated speak into the mic');
};
const voiceschanged = () => {
  console.log(`Voices #: ${speechSynthesis.getVoices().length}`)
  speechSynthesis.getVoices().forEach(voice => {
    console.log(voice.name, voice.lang)
  })
}
speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = voiceschanged
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
 const current = event.resultIndex;
 
 const transcript = event.results[current][0].transcript;
 content.textContent = transcript;
 readOutLoud(transcript);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
 recognition.start();
});

function readOutLoud(message) {
 
 const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
 speech.text = 'I dont know what you said';
 if(message.includes('how are you')) {
   const finalText = 
   greetings[Math.floor(Math.random() * greetings.length)];
   speech.text = finalText;
  
 } 
 if(['hey', 'hi', 'hello', 'hi there', 'hey there', 'hi techwala', 'hey techwala','hello techwala']
 .some(word => message.includes(word))) {
    const finalText = hello[Math.floor(Math.random() * hello.length)];
    speech.text = finalText;
 
}
 if(['whats your name', 'your name']
 .some(word => message.includes(word))) {
    const finalText = name[Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length)];
    speech.text = finalText;
}
if(['how\'s the weather', 'what\'s the weather like', 'is it sunny', 'is it raining', 'is it cloudy', 'is it snowing', 'what\'s the weather']
 .some(word => message.includes(word))) {
    const finalText = weather[Math.floor(Math.random() * weather.length)];
    speech.text = finalText;
}
 if(['I/m doing good', 'doing good', 'I\'m doing well', 'same old', 'I\'m fine', 'I\'m doing fine']
 .some(word => message.includes(word))) {
    const finalText = hru[0];
    speech.text = finalText;
} 
if(['what\'s your favorite color', 'what color do you like', 'favorite color', 'do you have a favorite color']
 .some(word => message.includes(word))) {
    const finalText = color[0];
    speech.text = finalText;
} 
speech.volume = 1;
 speech.rate = 1;
 speech.pitch = 1;
 window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
<body>
<button class="talk">Talk</button>
<h3 class="content"></h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The languages available depend on the browser. If it's not listed by .getVoices(), it's not there.

Comment: @HeyHeyJC So if It's not on the browser I can't use it? And even if en-IN isn't available en-GB still is but that isn't working either.